# Linking with .so in g++ results in undefined references

Tags: c++, linux, g++, shared-libraries

To keep this simple... assume I have the following: A.lib, libB.so (which uses A.lib), and C.exe (which uses libB.so).  Note: This is Linux, not Windows.  I'm just using .exe to convey binary type/purpose.

I'm just trying to compile and link C.exe form the command prompt as it's just a simple test program.  This is the line I'm using:

```
g++ -I../include C.cpp -o C.exe -L../lib -lB
```

The result is many undefined references to things that would be found in A.lib.  There are no errors referencing anything exported from libB.so.

If I copy libB.so to that same directory and use this command:

```
g++ -I../include C.cpp -o C.exe -lB
```

The result is C.exe is built and can be run without error.

Once libB.so is build I shouldn't need the libs that were used to build it. Despite this, I thought I would try something as a final attempt. I copied A.lib into the same lib directory as libB.so and tried the original build command again.  The result was the same.

Any and all thoughts appreciated.

Comment: How did you link `libB.so`? Did you explicitly link with `A.lib`?

Comment: Use the `-R` option, in addition to `-L`. See `ld`'s man page for more information.

Comment: By the way, is the `A` library a *static* library or a *dynamic* library?

Comment: @Some programmer dude - Sorry for being unclear.  A.lib is static and explicitly linked with libB.so.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - yup, that fixed it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SamVershavchik put me on the path to the answer.  I tried this command first:

```
g++ -I../include C.cpp -o C.exe -Wl,-R,../lib -lB
```

The result was a clean build but another error about missing symbols when I ran C.exe.

I modified the command to the following:

```
g++ -I../include C.cpp -o C.exe -Wl,-R,--just-symbols=../lib/libB.so -lB
```

This resulted in a clean build and the ability to run C.exe without error.